# How to create a simple view controller whose view bounces like a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What is the simple way to create UIViewController with view in it with some controls, that will bounce like it was big UITableViewCell in UITableView  ?

By bouncing, I mean if user moves his finger up and down the view will move like it was a UITableView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking to use a [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

The way to accomplish this is to set the `contentSize` equal to the `frame`'s `size`, and then set the `bounces` property to `YES`.

Something like this assuming you're working in the context of a `UIViewController`:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 460);
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
[scrollView setBounces:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:size];
[[self view] addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];

//add subviews to scrollView...
```

Comment: Can I create it in the interface builder ?

Comment: @megatron You should be able to.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). It will help you. `UITableView` itself is a subclass of `UIScrollView`